# python pandas read_fwf separate by \t

Tags: python, pandas, read-fwf

I have tried these variations,

```
df = pd.read_fwf("test.txt", sep='\t', header = 20, engine='python')
df = pd.read_fwf("test.txt", sep=r'\\t', header = 20, engine='python')
df = pd.read_fwf("test.txt", sep='\\\\t', header = 20, engine='python')

print(list(df.columns.values))
```

The result I get is,

['Column1name\tColumn2name\tColumn3name\tColumn4name\tColumn5name']

Comment: Please show a sample of your `text.txt` file, in the question.

Comment: are you sure you have fixed-width formatted lines file ?

Comment: It's a .txt file and the columns are separated by a tab, so I think it is a fixed width formatted file

Comment: Can you upload it somewhere, e.g. to pastebin.com? I can't reproduce.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't upload as it's work related. I tried separating by a space just to see if it would work, some column names have spaces in them, oddly it came it exactly the same as above.